# Change incoming Excel type to string

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, office-interop

I'm reading data from an Excel workbook using `openfiledialog`

```
String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML; HDR=YES; IMEX = 1\"; ";
```

the workbook is totally dynamic could be 5 columns or even 50 columns, I send the incoming data to datagridview using this

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
con.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
DataTable data = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(data);
for (int i = 0; i <= data.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < data.Columns.Count; z++)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        cb.DropDownWidth = 250;
        fillComboCell(cb);
        cb.Sorted = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[z] = cb;                          
        dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[z].Value = data.Columns[z];//Shows header of Dataset
        //Makes first line bold
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle boldStyle = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        boldStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
        dataGridView1.Rows[1].DefaultCellStyle = boldStyle;
        dataGridView1.Rows[i + 2].Cells[z].Value = data.Rows[i][z];
     }
}
con.Close();
con.Dispose();
```

There is no problem with reading the data with this code (I did not share all of my code as it is long, so this might not working when you copy it).

My problem is there is a column in my workbook that's formatted as "custom": hh:mm:ss to be specific. The values I see when I open the workbook look like this `09:52:17`,  but when I read the data into my datagridview it changes to this `30/12/1899 09:52:17`.

Here is my question: I don't need these values with custom types. All I want to do with this program is convert this Excel content into a xml file. The problem is I handle this cell as a string cell, like the other cells, and when I do it crashes my program. And because of dynamic excel files I can't tell which columns will be datetime or int or anything else. I've checked excel connection strings but couldn't find anything there, but I think it's something to do with the connection string. Can anyone help me to read the whole workbook's content as string only and without changing any values inside of it?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Excel reference libraries but are you able to get the cell format string from `dataGridView1.Rows[i + 2].Cells[z]` properties? If you can, then check this for your custom format string, you can then put an `if` statement to check for this and if true to say `(Convert.ToDateTime(data.Rows[i][z])).ToString("HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: The problem is there are many formats that I can select in excel, doing this for datatime will work for today but what if the user pass an excel with another custom cell? I need something that will convert every cell into string or something similar to this

Comment: The format selected in excel is ONLY for excel's GUI. The actual data stored does not change. If you are selecting from a cell that holds a date  or date/time you can always anticipate that it will be in this format. I agree that it's not optimal to have that date dimension hanging out there, but perhaps you can test if it's <=1900 and then just cast it to a string and substring that garbage off of there. Also "Garbage" is what you can expect from both Excel AND Ace and data clean up will be a big chunk of work here. I would anticipate a ton of edge cases. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized this ;

```
 for (int i = 2; i <= xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Playlist_Path_col != 0) { Playlist_Path = xlRange.Cells[i, Playlist_Path_col].Text; }
                    if (Playlist_Audio_Path_col != 0) { Playlist_Audio_Path = xlRange.Cells[i, Playlist_Audio_Path_col].Text; }
                    if (Playlist_Duration_col != 0) { Playlist_Duration = xlRange.Cells[i, Playlist_Duration_col].Text; }
                    if (Playlist_Auto_Start_col != 0) { Playlist_Auto_Start = xlRange.Cells[i, Playlist_Auto_Start_col].Text; }
                    if (Playlist_Date_col != 0) { Playlist_Date = xlRange.Cells[i, Playlist_Date_col].Text; }

                    if (Video_Path_col != 0) { Video_Path = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_Path_col].Text; }
                    if (Video_Audio_Path_col != 0) { Video_Audio_Path = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_Audio_Path_col].Text; }
                    if (Video_NameExt_col != 0) { Video_NameExt = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_NameExt_col].Text; }
                    if (Video_Name_col != 0) { Video_Name = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_Name_col].Text; }
                    if (Video_Note_col != 0) { Video_Note = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_Note_col].Text; }
                    if (Video_Category_col != 0) { Video_Category = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_Category_col].Text; }
                    if (Video_URL_col != 0) { Video_URL = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_URL_col].Text; }

                    if (Video_In_Time_col != 0) { Video_In_Time = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_In_Time_col].Text; }
                    if (Video_INOUT_Duration_col != 0) { Video_INOUT_Duration = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_INOUT_Duration_col].Text; }
                    if (Video_Width_col != 0) { Video_Width = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_Width_col].Text; }
                    if (Video_Height_col != 0) { Video_Height = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_Height_col].Text; }
                    if (Video_Rate_col != 0) { Video_Rate = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_Rate_col].Text; }
                    if (Video_Colorspace_col != 0) { Video_Colorspace = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_Colorspace_col].Text; }
                    if (Video_Aspect_Ratio_col != 0) { Video_Aspect_Ratio = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_Aspect_Ratio_col].Text; }
                    if (Video_Interlace_col != 0) { Video_Interlace = xlRange.Cells[i, Video_Interlace_col].Text; }

                    if (Audio_Channel_col != 0) { Audio_Channel = xlRange.Cells[i, Audio_Channel_col].Text; }
                    if (Audio_Channel_Bit_col != 0) { Audio_Channel_Bit = xlRange.Cells[i, Audio_Channel_Bit_col].Text; }
                    if (Audio_Bit_Rate_col != 0) { Audio_Bit_Rate = xlRange.Cells[i, Audio_Bit_Rate_col].Text; }

                    if (LiveSource_Path_col != 0) { LiveSource_Path = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Path_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_Audio_Path_col != 0) { LiveSource_Audio_Path = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Audio_Path_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_Name_col != 0) { LiveSource_Name = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Name_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_Note_col != 0) { LiveSource_Note = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Note_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_Category_col != 0) { LiveSource_Category = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Category_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_URL_col != 0) { LiveSource_URL = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_URL_col].Text; }

                    if (LiveSource_IN_Time_col != 0) { LiveSource_IN_Time = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_IN_Time_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_OUT_Time_col != 0) { LiveSource_OUT_Time = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_OUT_Time_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_INOUT_Duration_col != 0) { LiveSource_INOUT_Duration = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_INOUT_Duration_col].Text; }

                    if (LiveSource_Width_col != 0) { LiveSource_Width = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Width_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_Height_col != 0) { LiveSource_Height = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Height_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_Rate_col != 0) { LiveSource_Rate = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Rate_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_Colorspace_col != 0) { LiveSource_Colorspace = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Colorspace_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_Aspect_Ratio_col != 0) { LiveSource_Aspect_Ratio = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Aspect_Ratio_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_Interlace_col != 0) { LiveSource_Interlace = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Interlace_col].Text; }

                    if (LiveSource_Channel_col != 0) { LiveSource_Channel = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Channel_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_Channel_Bit_col != 0) { LiveSource_Channel_Bit = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Channel_Bit_col].Text; }
                    if (LiveSource_Bit_Rate_col != 0) { LiveSource_Bit_Rate = xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Bit_Rate_col].Text; }
```

I was using xlRange.Cells[i, LiveSource_Bit_Rate_col].Value2;
so this command was giving me the value of the cell but it was also giving me the value with its format.. so I searched again and I found .Text  instead of .Value2 and it worked very well.. and in filling my datagridview I used this

```
 string[] format = new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" };
                            DateTime datetime;
                            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(data.Rows[i][z].ToString(), format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out datetime))
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i + 2].Cells[z].Value = datetime.ToString("hh:MM:ss");
                            else
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i + 2].Cells[z].Value = data.Rows[i][z];
```

It's a bit tricky but working really good currently..